# Errors cloning Git server Ubuntu 14

Tags: git, apache, ubuntu

I have just installed Git on my server Ubuntu 14 following these steps:

http://jmuras.com/blog/2012/git-server-with-apache-authentication-on-ubuntudebian/

I made a little change when creating Git.conf and symbolic link cause goes on different folders for Ubuntu 14, I did it on:

```
/etc/apache2/conf-available/git.conf
```

And symbolic link on:

```
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/git.conf  => /etc/apache2/conf-available/git.conf
```

Everythings seems to work fine, but when I try to clone the project, after authenticate got this error:

> fatal:
>   http://testserver.com/git/newProject/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
>   not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

And on Apache access log:

> 192.168.70.1 - user [18/May/2014:16:24:54 -0700] "GET /git/newProject/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 404 457
>   "-" "git/1.8.0.msysgit.0"
>
> 404 error

Comment: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Comment: yes, i did it on git repo folder, same result

Comment: what is the exact command that resulted in that fatal message?

Comment: after i made git clone and authenticate succesfully

Comment: "exact command" means something like `git clone http://testserver.com/git/newProject` - Is this the line you typed?

Comment: yes i used that command

Answer (score 0):

According to your access log, your git client is trying to access `/git/newProject/info/refs`, but the server could not find that file (404).

You probably did not configure your server correctly. Your mentioned tutorial creates a repository "agilesparkle". If you call your repository "newProject" you have to replace all occurrences of "agilesparkle" with "newProject".

Also make sure that your server is using `/var/www/` as [document root](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#documentroot) as this is the place you probably created your `git/newProject` folder.

Also make sure you reload the server configuration after making any changes.

Comment: michas, as you said i replaced all occurrences "agilesparkle" for "newProject",when you said "document root" means public folder?, my server is using as public folder /var/www/html, should i put git folder on /var/www/html ?

Comment: If your [document root](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#documentroot) is `/var/www/` and you configured `<Location /git/newProject>` in your config file, then an access to  http://testserver.com/git/newProject/info/refs should try to look for `/var/www/git/newProject/info/refs` on the server.